# ANTLR4 parse tree doesn't contain rule names

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr4, grammar

ANTLR4 doesn't show rule names in parse tree.

For example, `1 + 2` is printed as:

[image: Simple expression's tree]

Code in main:

```cpp
    std::string test = "1 + 2";
    ANTLRInputStream input(test);
    GrammarLexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    GrammarParser parser(&tokens);

    auto *tree = parser.expression();

    std::cout << tree->toStringTree(true) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dived into ANTLR's C++ runtime source code and found these 2 functions:

```cpp
/// Print out a whole tree, not just a node, in LISP format
/// {@code (root child1 .. childN)}. Print just a node if this is a leaf.
virtual std::string toStringTree(bool pretty = false) = 0;

/// Specialize toStringTree so that it can print out more information
/// based upon the parser.
virtual std::string toStringTree(Parser *parser, bool pretty = false) = 0;
```

So, to fix the "error", replace

```cpp
tree->toStringTree(true)
```

with

```cpp
tree->toStringTree(&parser, true)
```